# Spark Job creation time

Tags: java, apache-spark

How to access Job creation time using taskcontext. 
I'm planing to get this time in the different executors and set it with persisting data which is help full in later processes. Since job creation time is unique even when when retrieved from different executors  it helps to keep track of persisted data in a one job.

Is it possible to get from `TaskMetrics`?
How to access Jobdata class ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could do this using  listeners.  I had to extend the class SparkListners and track when a job ( all the tasks for a job) ends and start and perform actions depending  on that.